# SSO for Salesforce Sites

Tags: apex, visualforce, single-sign-on, login

I have a force.com site which is used by external users.

I want to have SSO authentication from an external IDP, SAML.

I prefer it to be when a param is transferred on the URL site - check it on the server side and redirect to the IDP for auth.

And if the param is not there, I want to display the general site.

On the Server side, I'll display data, based on this param.

Is there a way to do it?

If not, an auth before entering the site with this external IDP will be great also.

I tried to use this link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_sites.htm&type=5

But I don't have community users So I didn't understand where I should get the params from?

I'm new to the SSO thing, so If you can, please be detailed in your answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSO means Single Sign on ...means require platform where someone needs to sign in (login)... but your current platform is public Salesforce site which do not require login...standard SSO will not work along with guest user...If you want something like parametrized redirection/authentication... you need to build custom solutions:

1. Use VF page as home page of site and place all your logic there. OR
2. Use site URL Rewriter class to control redirection as explained here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm